# Julia - MethodError: no method matching is less (::Float64, ::Tuple{Int64,Int64})

Tags: julia

My question is about why do I get this error if I have defined all variables as Float64. There shouldm't be a problem.

Here is the code and the message I get

```
pr = Array{Float64}(1001)
succ = Array{Float64}(1001)

pr1 = Float64
pr2 = Float64
pr3 = Float64
pr4 = Float64
pr5 = Float64

succ1 = Float64
succ2 = Float64
succ3 = Float64
succ4 = Float64
succ5 = Float64

pr1 = 100,0
pr2 = 80,0
pr3 = 50,0
pr4 = 30,0
pr5 = 0,0

succ1 = 0,5
succ2 = 0,6
succ3 = 0,85
succ4 = 0,95
succ5 = 1

x = Float64

for x = 1:1:1001
pr[x]= (x-1)/10

if pr[x] == pr5
  succ[x] = succ5
elseif pr[x] < pr4
  succ[x] = succ4 + (succ5 - succ4) * (pr5 - pr[x]) / (pr4-pr5)
elseif pr[x] < pr3
  succ[x] = succ3 + (succ4 - succ3) * (pr4 - pr[x]) / (pr3-pr4)
elseif pr[x] < pr2
  succ[x] = succ2 + (succ3 - succ2) * (pr3 - pr[x]) / (pr2-pr3)
elseif pr[x] < pr1
  succ[x] = succ1 + (succ2 - succ1) * (pr2 - pr[x]) / (pr1-pr2)
elseif pr[x] == pr1
  succ[x] = succ1

end

println(succ[x])

end
```

It has to do probably with integers and floating types but I do not see how as i have defined everything as Float64

Answer (score 5):

Don't do this: `pr1 = Float64`. You may think this defines `pr1` to be of type `Float64`, but you actually define `pr1` as an alias for the type name `Float64`. Just do `pr1 = 100.0` and Julia will know it is a `Float64`. You probably want to declare that assignment `const`though, `const pr1 = 100`, if you don't change it.

Also, you cant use `,` as a decimal separator in Julia. `pr1 = 100,0` sets the value of `pr1` to the Tuple `(100,0)`.